# Django Foreign Key Field assign one field with only one another field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create  model  TravelAgentDocumentType which consists of two ForeignKey's i.e travel_agent and document_type the plan is to have one travel agent can have only one document type, below are  my code snippet from models.

```
   class TravelAgentDocument(BaseModel):
        travel_agent = models.ForeignKey(TravelAgent, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        document_type = models.ForeignKey(
            DocumentType,
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
            null=True
        )
```

and TravelAgent model is

```
class TravelAgent(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        unique=True,
        validators=[validate_travel_agent_name]
    )
    office_location = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        validators=[validate_location],
    )
    office_land_line_number = LandLineNumberField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        unique=True,
        blank=True)
    office_phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
```

DocumentType model is

```
class DocumentType(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        unique=True,
        validators=[validate_document_name]
    )
```

how can I assign one travel agent with only one document type?

Comment: If one Agent can have only one document type why did you create many-to-many relationship

Comment: it is many to one relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) feature here.

```
class TravelAgentDocument(BaseModel):
        travel_agent = models.ForeignKey(TravelAgent, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        document_type = models.ForeignKey(
            DocumentType,
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
            null=True
        )

      class Meta:
          constraints = [
                models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['travel_agent', 'document_type'], name='name of constraint')
                    ]
```

Comment: unique_together = ['travel_agent', 'document_type'] i apparently ended up using this in meta class

Comment: `UniqueConstraint` provides more functionality than `unique_together`. `unique_together` may be deprecated in the future. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) @navaraj

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
Class Travel_agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        unique=True,
        validators=[validate_travel_agent_name]

        office_location = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        validators=[validate_location],
    )
    office_land_line_number = LandLineNumberField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        unique=True,
       blank=True)
    office_phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)

Class Agent_document(models.Model):
    docum = models.OneToOneField(Travel_agent, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
```

Comment: please squash your answers in one, use the edit button

Answer (score -1):

This is because in your travelagentdocument model you have created document_type field with foreign key.